# Remote Java Development using IntelliJ or Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

I have some code that only runs on a remote Ubuntu box with a gateway in between. Every time I have make some changes I have to make the change in my local Mac and push it to git and rebuild it on the box to see if it is working. Was wondering if there is a way to configure IntelliJ or Eclipse to modify code directly on the remote box and have it running there with debug etc. so that I minimize on the roundtrip?

Comment: So...you don't have a test suite, or a way to replicate the environment locally?

Comment: Nope there are linux related + environment related things that can't be replicated locally

Answer (score 0):

The solution may be to mount the remote filesystem in your local machine.
Then run the IDE off the remote file mount in the local system.

That way, the IDE will access all the files as if it is local.
The IDE can connect to the process running in remote machine.
Also the IDE can remote debug the JVM easily.

Here is the how to of mounting the remote file system locally
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-sshfs-to-mount-remote-file-systems-over-ssh